# Translating django tables2 template column header

Tags: django, django-tables2, django-i18n

Hi i'm working with django-tables2 and I have a table where I need to translate the headers of each column.

```
class ModelTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.columns.Column()
    edit = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href='{% url "edit_my_model_instance" record.id %}'>Edit</a>', verbose_name=u'Edit', )    
    delete = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href='{% url "del_my_model_instance" record.id %}'>Delete</a>', verbose_name=u'Delete', )    

    class Meta:
        model = models.Model
```

The above code without translations work fine, but when I add the gettext for translate like this :

```
  delete = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href='{% url "del_my_model_instance" record.id %}'>Delete</a>', verbose_name=_(u'Delete'), )
```

Where I added gettext as _ : `verbose_name=_(u'Delete')`

I receive the following error

> TypeError: 'TemplateColumn' object is not callable

The thing is if I use tables.Column it works fine with translation, so the problem is only when I user TemplateColumn.

If you can guide me through this I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks well related to the `verbose_name` parameter and should work that way.
But I think you wrongly used the single/double quotes in the first argument of the `TemplateColumn`. You should use:

```
delete = tables.TemplateColumn(
    '<a href="{% url "price-update" record.id %}">{% trans "Delete" %}</a>',
    verbose_name=_("Delete"),
)
```